# Only show column with X's

Tags: excel, vba

I have a massive Excel sheet with currently 100+ columns and 84 rows. I am looking to be able to toggle a specific row and have only the columns with text show, all others hidden. For example:

`TITLE |COLUMN 1|COLUMN 2|COLUMN 3|COLUMN 4|COLUMN 5|
 ROW 1 |   X    |        |   X    |        |   X    |
 ROW 2 |        |   X    |   X    |   X    |        |`

When I "toggle" ROW 1 only columns 1,3,5 will show and columns 2,4 will hide, all other rows will also hide.

When I "toggle" ROW 2 only columns 2,3,4 will show and columns 1,5 will hide, all other rows will also hide.

EDIT: Rows 1,2,3 and Columns A,B must always be visible.

Can this be done and what method do you suggest? ie: radio button, checkbox, etc...?

Comment: Will you ever want to do two rows at once? Like "toggle row 1 and 2" and show all those columns? (and say column 6 only had "x" in row 1, it would keep that column visible)

Comment: It would make things easier but is not mandatory.  I will ultimately be trying to make things go both ways as well, so I can toggle Column# and show only rows that have an X in that column.

Comment: If your table was transposed, you could do this with a simple filter, using all of Excel's built in filtering tick boxes and things would make it a lot easier!

Comment: Could you give me an example of what you mean? I am totally open to re-organizing, this is a new spreadsheet I have spent very little time with the layout on, I wanted the information first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @Wolfie - if you transpose the data, it'll make it *much* simpler to do.  However, this was a little fun to work on, so I have the below macro:

```
Sub toggleRows()
Dim mark As String
Dim rng As Range, cel As Range, totalRng As Range
Dim rowNum As String
mark = "x"

rowNum = InputBox("What ROW (#) do you want to filter?")
rowNum = Trim(rowNum)
If rowNum = "" Then Exit Sub

unhideAllColumns
Set totalRng = Range(Cells(4, 3), Cells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count, Cells(Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column))
totalRng.Select

For Each cel In totalRng
    If cel.Row <> rowNum Then
        cel.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Else
        cel.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        If cel.Value = "" Then ' changed from cel.Value <> mark
            cel.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Else
            cel.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        End If
    End If
Next cel

End Sub
```

and to show all columns:

```
Sub unhideAllColumns()
Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it show only that specific row and hide all the others? Also how can I change the value from "x" to be any value? I tried using * and that did not work, as some columns have additional text.

Comment: @Dazzled - In other words, if the cell has **any** value in it, show that and hide all *blank* cells?

Comment: Yes, I suppose. Also keeping rows 1,2,3 and columns A,B always visible as I have the main information in those.

Comment: @Dazzled - Can you please edit that into your OP? That's a material thing to know...I'll have to edit the code a lot.  However, Please see Dick's answer, as that's a bit better since it's not relying on a macro.

Comment: I fixed the OP to what I believe you asked.

Comment: @Dazzled - see the edited code. I think I have it. If not, please show us some more sample data and what you expect the output to look like.

Comment: I received an error "Sub or function not defined" within the code "unhideAllColumns". Also does this resolve the issue of there being any value and not limited to just "x"?

Comment: disregard, I realized that was from me altering the Sub name for the unhide. Also I added 'Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False' to the unhide command as before it was only unhiding the columns. Works perfect as I can tell. Thank you!

Comment: @Dazzled - Glad it works!  And yeah, I forgot to update the second to include rows. But for the record I've added that in.

Answer (score 0):

For the transpose solution, here are the steps:

1. Select your data

[image]

2. Copy (Ctrl+C). Select a cell in column A below the original data. Paste Special Transpose

[image]

[image]

3. Delete the original data

[image]

4. Add filters from the Data Ribbon (Alt+D+F+F)

[image]

5. Pull down the `ROW 1` dropdown and filter on X

[image]

Comment: I do appreciate this response, after giving it a try I don't know if I like the format. Does it have to switch the rows and columns?

Comment: If you want to use the built-in filters, you have to transpose. If you don't want to transpose, you'll have to roll your own. It looks like @BruceWayne gave you a solution that works.